# More direct approach to a combinatorial problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics, alternative-proof

Suppose we randomly arrange $n$ objects of which $s$ are of silver, $1$ is of gold and the remaining $n-s-1$ are of copper.

The question I looked at is:

> what is the probability that all eventual predecessors of the golden object are of silver?

We could rephrase this as:

> what is the probability that among the eventual predecessors of the golden object are no copper objects.

I defined the described event as $E$ and approached the answer by first defining $E_i$ (this for $i=0,1,\dots,s$) as the event that the golden object is on spot $i+1$ and its predecessors are all of silver.

Then we find:$$P(E_i)=\frac1n\binom{s}i\binom{n-1}i^{-1}=\frac1n\binom{n-1}s^{-1}\binom{n-i-1}{n-s-1}$$
and making use of the hockey-stick identity we arrive at:$$P(E)=\sum_{i=0}^sP(E_i)=\frac1n\binom{n-1}s^{-1}\binom{n}{n-s}=\frac1{n-s}$$

That is a nice result. So nice that IMV it clearly indicates the existence of more direct way to find it. I tried to, but failed.

So my question is:

> Can you provide me a more direct solution?

Thank you for taking notice of this and sorry in advance if this appears to be a duplicate question.

---

**Edit**

My original question did not mention the word "copper" neither the rephrasing of the question that uses the word "copper". In my (narrow) thinking I was purely focused on gold and silver. This fact provided the blind spot that I am now released from.

In situations like this a sort of battle takes place within me. I am very eager to find the smart solution **myself**. I can pose it as a question but my pride first forbids me to do so. After some struggling I set this (stupid) pride aside and decide to show my shortcomings. A healthy process.

Thank you all for your answers.

Comment: Do you mean that the gold object is preceded by a continuous line of all silver objects ?

Comment: @trueblueanil the gold one is preceded *only* by silver ones. Not necessarily all silver ones. So possibilities are: G.., SG.., SSG.. , et cetera.

Comment: Suppose the other objects are of copper, then do you mean that all silver objects must come somewhere before the single gold object, and the copper ones can be anywhere ?

Comment: @trueblueanil If the others are of copper then you can reformulate: what is the probability that the golden one has no predecessors that are of copper? It is **not** necessary that *all* silver ones are predecessors of the golden one.

Comment: "no copper predecessors" is a strange phrasing.  I feel like the problem becomes a bit easier when that is rephrased as "the golden object must come before all of the copper objects".  (The other key insight is that the silver doesn't matter at all.)

Comment: @Teepeemm Originally my question did not mention copper objects. By means of an edit (not from me) coppers were added and because some answers started mentioning copper I could not take it away anymore. I edited and hope that things are clear now.

Comment: (1) Observe that we must refer to the Copper in the all **"Simpler Solutions"** ( including mine ) , @Teepeemm , hence that is the **"key wording"** which resolves the Issue. (2) When we refer to only gold & Silver ( without referring to Copper ) the Answer becomes highly complicated , which was what triggered this Question. (3) We can not **"unsee"** that Edit , but I think that Edit was the trigger towards the Intuitive Solutions here.

Comment: @Prem See my last edit. It confirms the essence of your comment.

Comment: Thanks for that update , @drhab , I have generally noticed that **"Correctly Identifying"** things will make it **"Easy to Proceed"** to grasp the Situation [[ The Other Side is to **"Ignore Irrelevant"** things , which is Equally Important ]]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Lay down all the copper and gold coins. The probability that the gold coin is first is $\frac1{n-s}$.

Comment: There are more good answers of course but this one I choose for acceptance. It is nice, concise and leaves me unpuzzled about anything. The observation "golden coin first" is indeed exactly the same as "among the predecessors of the golden are only silver coins". Thank you!

Comment: In some ways this answer may be even clearer (at least this is the way I thought of it before I checked the provided answers) if "copper and gold" had been put in quote marks or written equivalently as "non-silver".  I think @drhab's difficulty stemmed from conceptualising the question as having three "equally important" categories of coin: "gold", "copper", and "silver". When viewed as a hierarchy, at the top level "gold and copper"/"non-silver" vs "silver", with the former having subcategories of "gold" vs "copper" separately, the fundamental insight seems more obvious (at least to me)

Answer (score 4):

The key insight I got while editing the Question to include Copper Objects is this :  **We do not want to count the number of ways , we only want the Probability !**

We can start with $(n-s-1)$ Copper Coins.
We can put the gold coin at start or middle or else where. That is $(n-s-1+1)=(n-s)$ ways.
This is the Initial Order , where "favourable" is $1$ (When gold is at Start) , "unfavourable" is $(n-s-1)$ (When is gold is not at Start) , "total" is $(n-s)$.

We can then put the Silver Coins in various Positons.
Each Initial Order will give $X$ Eventual Orders , where calculating $X$ is Cumbersome , involving various Summations & factorials.

Probability is $\frac{1 \times X}{(n-s) \times X}$
Thus we get the Probability Directly , without calculating $X$ , which will cancel !

Answer (score 3):

In any given arrangement of the $n$ objects, glue the $s$ silver objects in place and cyclically permute the other $n-s$ objects (the gold one and the unspecial ones). Exactly $1$ of those $n-s$ cyclic permutations, namely the one with the gold object placed before all the neutral objects, will have the property that the gold object is preceded by only silver objects.

Comment: Please check my thinking. I have a circle of $n$ open spots. Then I place the silver ones randomly. Then randomly I choose one of the points and promote it as first one (and choose for e.g. clockwise as direction). To get the situation that is described in my answer there is only one suitable spot for the golden object, but there are $n-s$ candidates. So the probability on arriving there is $1/(n-s)$. Is this in accordance with your answer, Greg?

Answer (score 2):

- From the right end, fill all the copper objects with the gold one immediately after the copper ends, $Pr= \frac{1}{n-s}$
- Intermingle the silver objects anywhichway in the row

Comment: if s=0, it is possible that all predecessors of golden object are silver, it occurs when golden object has no predecessor, so 1/n ; and your formula says 0 instead of 1/n.

Comment: In the time that I got the intent of the question and had lunch, some answers have already come, which I noticed only after reposting.